# PowerShell Package Management - Repository vs Provider vs Source

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget, package-management, powershellget

I am trying to understand package management in PowerShell, and I am getting an incomplete picture.  When I look at the objects PSRepository, PackageProvider, and PackageSource, they all seem to have the following relationships:

- A **PSRepository** can provide zero or more PowerShell modules.  A **PSRepository** must have one, and only one, **PackageProvider**.  An example of a repository is `PSGallery`.
- A **PackageProvider** can serve zero or more **PSRepository** objects.  A **PackageProvider** must have one or more **PackageSource** objects.  A **PackageProvider** is sometimes referred to as a "Package Manager".  Some examples of package providers include `NuGet`, `Chocolatey`, or `PowerShellGet`.
- A **PackageSource** must serve one and only one **PackageProvider**.  Some examples of package sources include `nuget.org`, `MyCustomVSTSFeed`, or `PSGallery`.

I've looked at the following links, but it still doesn't provide a clear picture of how they are related.

- [About PackageManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_packagemanagement?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Getting Started with the PSGallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/getting-started?view=powershell-7.1)

1. Why does a **PSRepository** have a
   property called *PackageManagementProvider* of type **string**
   instead of type **PackageProvider**?
2. Why does a **PSRepository** have its own *SourceLocation* property, if it already has a source reference through its provider?
3. Why is `PSGallery` both a **PackageSource** and a **PSRepository**?
4. Why is `PowerShellGet` both the name of a module that provides access to the gallery, and the name of a **PackageProvider**?

Comment: Maybe a repository is a combination of provider and source?  And sources only have a provider property because sources only work with certain providers?

Comment: And why does Find-Package not work with PackageSources but PSRepository locations?

Comment: As an aside it looks like they will be changing the way some of this works with a major version update of PowerShellGet in 7.2. Here's [an article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-team-2021-investments/?WT.mc_id=modinfra-0000-thmaure) by the projects principal engineering manager

Comment: Good find!  PowerShellGet 3.0 looks promising.

Comment: @Efie I have added a note to the answer now that Preview 11 of PowerShellGet 3.0 is out. Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update August 2021

PowerShellGet 3.0 will be **fundamentally different** from previous versions of the module. It will no longer be dependent on *PackageManagment*, uses the NuGet APIs and libraries directly (as opposed to `nuget.exe`) and has new syntax. You can learn more about the ongoing development of PowerShellGet 3.0 from the [DevBlogs Article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershellget-3-0-preview-11-release/) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet#important-note).

The question and answer on this page are therefore relevant only to PowerShellGet 2.0.

---

The best way to think of this is as two *spheres*; the **PackageManagement** one and the **PowerShellGet** one.

### *PackageManagement*

**PackageManagement** (formerly OneGet) is the outer sphere, and is a framework for package delivery in Windows. It is administered through PowerShell, but applies to the whole operating system or user profile. It provides two main classes:

- A **PackageProvider** is the equivalent of a package manager; think *APT/dpkg*, *pacman*, *Homebrew*, *Chocolatey/NuGet*, or *winget*. These utilise the framework to manage software on Windows using the concept of packages.
- A **PackageSource** serves a single *PackageProvider* and is where the provider gets its packages from.

### *PowerShellGet*

**PowerShellGet** is the inner sphere, and is a PowerShell **module** that uses the *PackageManagement* framework to deliver packages **specifically for PowerShell**. It is registered as a *PackageProvider*, and uses the associated *PackageSources* to deliver **modules** and **scripts** from the PowerShell Gallery, or additional sources. It introduces a new class, called a **PSRepository**. You can think of this as a virtual wrapper for a *PackageSource* that only exists in the *PowerShellGet* sphere.

When you register a new *PSRepository* with `Register-PSRepository`, you'll notice that if you run `Get-PackageSource`, a new source has been automatically added with the same name and URI, for the *PowerShellGet* provider. The *PSRepository* has a few specific functions:

- To limit changes made to within the PowerShell universe; none of the *PowerShellGet* Cmdlets modify operating system components or software.
- To differentiate between module packages and script packages, and to install them in the correct locations.
- To permit manual updating of the above with the `Update-*` Cmdlets.
- To **permit publishing of packages back to the *PSRepository* source**.

For (un)installing/updating modules and scripts, *PowerShellGet* uses the *PackageManagement* Cmdlets. For publishing scripts and modules, it uses the **.NET CLI** command `dotnet nuget push` after wrapping them in a `nupkg` archive.

### Summary

In light of the above, we can now answer the four points in the question:

1. The *PSRepository* is a custom object and wrapper for a *PackageSource*; it stores a `string` property called *PackageManagementProvider* which can be used with `Get-PackageProvider` to access the *PackageProvider* object.
2. *PSRepository* objects have custom properties that allow for different URIs for modules, scripts, retrieving and publishing.
   These are **SourceLocation** and **PublishLocation** for modules, and **ScriptSourceLocation** and **ScriptPublishLocation** for scripts.
3. *PowerShellGet* uses the *PackageManagement* framework in the background, so every *PSRepository* has a matching *PackageSource* used in backend operations.
4. The *PowerShellGet* module registers itself as a *PackageProvider* in its manifest, in order to interact with the framework and provide the customised functionality that it does. It also interacts with the NuGet *PackageProvider*.

In short, when you're dealing with software packages outside of PowerShell, you work directly with the *PackageManagement* framework. When you're dealing with modules and scripts *for* PowerShell, you work with *PowerShellGet*, which gives you abstracted access to the framework and NuGet.

Sources:

- [About PackageManagement - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_packagemanagement?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PackageManagement Module - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PowerShellGet Module - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PowerShellGet 2.2.5 - PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/2.2.5)
- [PackageManagement 1.4.7 - PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.4.7)

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you very much!  I was viewing the inheritance structure upside-down.  [I've written some pseudo-code to help visualize what you've said.](https://i.ibb.co/X38GKL3/psuedo-Package-Management.png)